# Proving difference of two powers using induction

Tags: proof-verification, summation, induction

Prove, that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ the following identity holds:
$$a^n - b^n = (a-b)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} a^k b^{n-k-1}.$$

---

For $n = 1$ we get $a^1 - b^1 = a - b$ on LHS, and on RHS we get $(a-b)\sum_{k=0}^{0}a^k b^{n-k-1} = a-b.$ Both sides are equal, so identity hold for $n = 1$.

---

Assume that for $m \in \mathbb{N}, n = m$ identity is generally true. For $m = n+1$ we get:
$$(a-b)\sum_{k=0}^{m}a^k b^{m-k}.$$
Multiplying and distributing we get:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{m}a^{k+1}b^{m-k} - \sum_{k =0}^{m}a^k b^{m-k+1}.$$

What shall I do after the last step? Is there some rule/identity, which I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can re-index the first sum in your last expression.  If you decrease $k$ by one in the summand, you can pay for it by increasing the limits.  So you'd get
$$\sum_{k=1}^{m+1} a^kb^{m-k} - \sum_{k=0}^{m} a^kb^{m-k}.$$

Now if you separate the last term of the first sum and the first term of the
second sum you have:

$$a^{m+1}b^0+ \sum_{k=1}^{m} a^kb^{m-k} - \sum_{k=1}^{m} a^kb^{m-k}-a^0b^m.$$

And the two summations cancel.

Answer (score 1):

Using induction hypothesis for $n$, we have
$$a^{n+1}-b^{n+1}=a(a^n-b^n)+(a-b)b^n=(a-b)\left[a\sum_{i+j=n-1}a^ib^j\right]+(a-b)b^n$$ $$a^{n+1}-b^{n+1}=(a-b)\left[a^n+a^{n-1}b+.....+b^n\right]=(a-b)\sum_{i+j=n}a^ib^j$$

Answer (score 0):

To prove that 
$$b^n-a^n =(b-a)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}b^ka^{n-1-k}$$
It suffices to show that $$b^n-1 = (b-1)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}b^k,$$
as follows:
$$\begin{align}
(b-1)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}b^k &=b\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}b^k-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}b^k\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}b^{k+1}-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}b^k\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n}b^{k}-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}b^k\\
&=b^{n}-1\\
\end{align}$$